# Fetch fires every second "onChange"

Tags: reactjs

Somehow my fetch only fires every second time, I select an item from list:

```
export default function App() {

...

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchBookData(books).then((payload) => setPayload(payload));
  }, [books]);

  
  const fetchBooksBySubject = () => {
      const options = {
        method: `GET`,
      };
      fetch(`${server}/books?subjects_like=${selectedValue}`, options)
      .then((response) => {
        if(response.ok){
          return response.json().then(setBookList)
        }
          throw new Error('Api is not available') 
        })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching data: ', error)
        setError(error)
      })
  }

  const handleChange = e => {
    setSelectedValue(e);
    fetchBooksBySubject();
  };

  if (!payload) {
    return <div>Please start the server</div>;
  }
  console.log(bookList)
  return (
    <div className="bg-blue-200">
      <div className="container mx-auto py-36 bg-blue-200">
        <div className="mt-12 px-96">
          <SubjectSelector 
            options={payload}
            selectedVal={selectedValue}
            handleChange={handleChange}/>
          <ShowcaseBooks selectedVal={selectedValue} />
          <ul>
            {bookList?.map((item) => {
              return(
                <li>{item.title}</li>
              )
            }
            )}
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}
```

So fetchBooksBySubject delivers the bookList first as emty array, then logs correctly, howeverso I have to select two times, to see `<li>{item.title}</li>` updated. Why is this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `selectedValue` isn't really updated yet (it will happen only at the next rerender) at the point when you call `fetchBooksBySubject`. It happens because `setSelectedValue` doesn't update the associated value immediately.

As a result, `` fetch(`${server}/books?subjects_like=${selectedValue}`, options) `` gets an old value.

You could fix it with i.e. useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchBooksBySubject();
}, [selectedValue])
```

instead of calling `fetchBooksBySubject` immediately in the callback

Comment: Now it fetches the old value and the new value on every update `books?subjects_like=Fiction books?subjects_like=Science` - is there any way to fix it?